# Definition of a reflection as an isometric, involutory, linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, reflection

In $V = \mathbb{R}^n$, a reflection through a linear subspace $S \subset V$ of dimension $k \leq n$ can be defined to be the linear map $R : V \rightarrow V$ that satisfies

\begin{equation} 
v \in S \implies Rv = v, \quad v \in S^\perp \implies Rv = -v. \qquad (1) 
\end{equation}

(This is a generalization of the usual notion of a reflection, in which $k = n - 1$.)

According to the second paragraph of [the Wikipedia article on reflections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)), this definition seems to be equivalent to defining $R$ to be a linear map that is isometric ($\forall v, ||Rv|| = ||v||$) and involutory ($R^2 = 1$). However, I am having trouble coming up with a proof of this statement. The forward direction is easy, since any map that satisfies $(1)$ has a full set of eigenvalues that are $\pm 1$, so the involutory and isometry properties follow trivially. However, how does one prove the converse?

Comment: If you're an isometric involution, what eigenvalues can you have?  By isometry, all eigenvalues are of modulus 1.  And if any eigenvalues are not $ \pm 1 $, then the corresponding eigenvector $ v $ is not sent to $ v $ by $ R^2 $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $R$ is an involutory isometry.  Then in particular $R$ is normal (since it is an isometry), so it is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ and its eigenspaces are orthogonal to each other.  But since $R^2=1$, its only eigenvalues can be $1$ and $-1$, so $R$ is in fact diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ and $V$ splits as an orthogonal direct sum of the eigenspaces with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$.  Let $S$ be the eigenspace of $R$ with eigenvalue $1$, so $S^\perp$ is the eigenspace with eigenvalue $-1$.  We then have $Rv=v$ for all $v\in S$ and $Rv=-v$ for all $v\in S^\perp$, so $R$ is the reflection through $S$.